# Css for line. How can i do it

Tags: css, line

[image]

I'm coding css, but I can't do it. Please, help me. How can I do ?

my css

```
.dvCareerLine
{        
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    background: #f36506;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to code a straight line using CSS?

Comment: yes, can you help me